# React 'x' is missing in props validation warning (eslint)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object, prop

I have tried many combination but could not ix the following error in React app:

> 'roles' is missing in props validation

Here is related code parts:

```
const ProRoute = ({ roles = [] }) => {
  const userRoles = service.getCurrentUser()?.roles;
  const isAuthorized = !roles.length || roles.some((r) => userRoles.includes(r));

  // ...
};

export default ProRoute;
```

and pass roles as shown below:

```
<Route element={<ProRoute roles={['ROLE_ADMIN']} />}>
  <Route index element={<Student />} />
</Route>
```

So, what is the cause of the problem? And should I get the roles in curly braces, brackets or etc?

Comment: Are you using PropTypes? you might be missing something there while defining proptypes for this component.

Comment: What is it? Actually I am new in React and someone suggest to install it I think, but I am not sure if I have to. So, by default, what should I do to solve the problem?

Comment: It is a typechecking library for react so that we can find and avoid bugs while doing development. If you are not sure and don't want to use it you can simply remove all the references of proptypes from your code. or else you can learn how to use it. There are lot of articles on internet for its usage. Ref: https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html

Comment: I see that I am using it and want to use it as it helps to write better code. Then, how should I pass roles and fix that problem?

Answer (score 0):

Like i mentioned in the comments. You need to learn how to use library before using it.

The error above comes because there must be a rule enabled in your eslintrc file called **react/prop-types**. This basically tells eslint to check for props and their types. This ensures that your components always receives expected props.

To fix the above error you can just add your roles prop in the propTypes object

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const ProRoute = ({ roles = [] }) => {
  const userRoles = service.getCurrentUser()?.roles;
  const isAuthorized = !roles.length || roles.some((r) => userRoles.includes(r));

  // ...
};

// Prop validation
ProRoute.propTypes = {
  roles: PropTypes.array
};

export default ProRoute;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you are right. In this case, there is no problem with the line of `const ProRoute = ({ roles = [] }) => {`.  Right?

Comment: Yes. That line is fine. I cannot upvote or mark the post as answer. only you can do that as you are post creator.

Comment: I mean upvote for the question, then I will mark as answer and upvote